# React Hook Form: errors is always empty

Tags: react-hook-form

There's been some other answers that say to set `mode: 'onBlur'` but this does not fix my errors state, even after updating to the latest RHF v7.45.2.

Here's my `useForm`:

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    control,
    reset,
    setValue,
    formState: { isSubmitting, errors, isValid },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { password: '' },
    mode: 'onBlur',
  });
```

I'm passing the errors object to my `TextField` custom component as such:

```
<TextInput
                name='password'
                label='Create Password'
                type='password'
                control={control}
                errors={errors?.password?.message}
                required={true}
                helperText='Must contain at least 8 characters'
              />
```

And here is how i'm rendering the component:

```
  ...

  if (type === 'password') {
    rules['minLength'] = 8;
  }

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={({
          field: { onChange, value },
          fieldState: { error, invalid },
        }) => {
          return (
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for={name}>
                {label} {required ? `*` : ''}
              </Label>
              <Input
                type={type}
                autoComplete={autoComplete}
                onChange={onChange}
                label={label}
                variant='filled'
                value={value || ''}
              />
              {helperText && (
                <FormText sx={{ marginLeft: 0, fontSize: 10, color: 'black' }}>
                  {helperText}
                </FormText>
              )}
              {errors && <FormFeedback>{errors}</FormFeedback>}
            </FormGroup>
          );
        }}
        rules={rules}
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
```

At the parent level, logging `errors` always shows `{}` even though `isValid` is false. The `error` at the field level is also null.

So it is validating, but errors is always empty and so I can never show the error message.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.